# AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

Totally new to deep learning can't figure out what is happening. I'm implementing a django app to recognize face in real time. Installed packages using pip and conda in two different envs but didn't get any success. Here I'm using MTCNN to detect faces after that I've model to recognize face. While things are running fine without django they are not working with django. 
Update - found one more thing - this script is not even running while testing it individually(without django) and with Keras==2.2.5. I believe it has some problem with MTCNN.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdamp.png%60)

```
import cv2
```

import pickle
from PIL import Image
from numpy import load
from numpy import expand_dims
from numpy import asarray
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

class RealTimeFaceDetection:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.stroke = 1
    self.detector = MTCNN()
    self.video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.color = (255, 0, 0)
    print("Loading pre-trained Keras model for face recognition")
    self.keras_model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5', compile=False)
    print("Face recognition model loaded successfully...")
    print("Loading pre-trained SVC model")
    self.svc_model = pickle.load(open('FACENET_MODEL.sav', 'rb'))
    print("Loading successful...")
    self.emb_data = load('5-celebrity-faces-embeddings.npz')

def img_to_array(self, face_img_pixels, required_size=(160, 160)):
    image = Image.fromarray(face_img_pixels)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    return asarray(image)

# Get the face embedding for one face
def get_embedding(self, model, face_pixels):
    face_pixels = face_pixels.astype('float32')
    mean, std = face_pixels.mean(), face_pixels.std()
    face_pixels = (face_pixels - mean) / std
    samples = expand_dims(face_pixels, axis=0)
    yhat = model.predict(samples)
    return yhat[0]

def get_encoder(self):
    trainy = self.emb_data['arr_1']
    # Label encode targets
    out_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    out_encoder.fit(trainy)
    return out_encoder

def find_faces(self):
    out_encoder = self.get_encoder()
    while(self.video_cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = self.video_cap.read()
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pixels = asarray(rgb_image)
        all_faces = self.detector.detect_faces(pixels)
        for face in all_faces:
            x1, y1, width, height = face['box']
            x1, y1 = abs(x1), abs(y1)
            x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
            face_arr = self.img_to_array(pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2])
            face_emb = self.get_embedding(self.keras_model, face_arr)
            samples = expand_dims(face_emb, axis=0)
            yhat_class = self.svc_model.predict(samples)
            yhat_prob = self.svc_model.predict_proba(samples)
            class_index = yhat_class[0]
            class_probability = yhat_prob[0, class_index] * 100
            class_probability = round(class_probability)
            if class_probability > 95.0:
                predict_names = out_encoder.inverse_transform(yhat_class)
                print('Predicted: %s (%f)' % (predict_names[0], class_probability))
            else:
                print("Low accuracy, probability = %f" % (class_probability))
```